# How to merge a none time series data table to time series table

Tags: pandas, merge

I have two table need to combine together. df1 and df2,and the format is below
df1:
time          A        B     C
12/12/2023   banana   buy    100
12/11/2023   banana   buy    100
12/10/2023   banana   buy    100
12/09/2023   apple    buy    100
12/08/2023   orange   buy    100
df2:
A        B
Apple   target
Banana  sam

The result I want is to combine df2 to df1, and with df1.A=df2.A.
Thanks

result:
time          A        B     C        D
12/12/2023   banana   buy    100     sam
12/11/2023   banana   buy    100     sam
12/10/2023   banana   buy    100     sam
12/09/2023   apple    buy    100     target
12/08/2023   orange   buy    100     nan